# Unable to find Writable inside Action.async in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

Appears I am missing something but here is what I have got (posting only relevant piece). where MyService.save returns Future[Option[MyCompany] ].

```
 def myPost = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
 val mn = Json.fromJson[MyEntity](request.body)
 mn.map{
   case m : MyEntity => MyService.save(m).map{f=> 
     f.map(mm=> Ok(mm ) ) 
   }

 }.recoverTotal {
    e => Future { BadRequest("Detected error:" + JsError.toFlatJson(e)) }
 }


 }
```

Although I have defined

```
implicit val companyWriter: Writes[MyCompany] = (...)
```

And this implicit is in the scope, it shows compile error

```
 Cannot write an instance of MyCompany to HTTP response. Try to define 
 a Writeable[MyCompany]
```

FYI: This writer is used elsewhere where I do Json.toJson(myCompany) and over there it finds and works fine. 
Anything in particular to async Ok that it's missing?

**EDIT**
It appears that Ok() method cannot figure out the MyCompany needs to be transformed to json. following seems to have worked.

```
Ok(Json.toJson(mm) )
```

Is this because arguments to Ok can vary? Separately there are too many "map" in the  above code. Any recommendation for improvement and making it more concise ?

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler error is about a `Writeable`, not a `Writes`.  `Writeables` are used to convert whatever you have to something that can be written to an HTTP response, `Writes` are used to marshall objects to JSON.  The names can be a little confusing.

As for style...

```
def myPost = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.validate[MyEntity] map { myEntity =>

    MyService.save(myEntity).map { maybeCompany =>

      maybeCompany match {
        case Some(company) => Ok(Json.toJson(company))
        case None          => NoContent // or whatever's appropriate
      }

    }

  } recoverTotal { t =>
    Future { BadRequest("Detected error: " + JsError.toFlatJson(e)) }
  }

}
```